# Expected ratio of x'Ax and x'AAx on a unit sphere?

Tags: normal-distribution, circular-statistics

Suppose $A$ is symmetric positive definite matrix. Is there a nice expression for the first moment of the following quantity?

$$\frac{x^TAx}{x^TA^2 x}$$

Where $x$ is distributed as $\text{Normal}(0,I_n)$. This is the ratio of two quadratic forms evaluated on the surface of the sphere.

When $A$ has eigenvalues $\langle 1, \frac{1}{2}\rangle$, this expectation is equal to $\frac{4}{3}$, visualized below ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-ratio-quadratic.nb))

[image]

**Edit Aug 18**
To expand on hyperplane's answer, we can take $A$ to be diagonal without loss of generality and write solution as

$$E\left[\frac{x^TAx}{x^TA^2 x}\right]=\langle a, z\rangle$$

Where
$$\begin{align}
a_i=&\frac{1}{A_{ii}}\\
z_i=&E_{y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,A)} \frac{y_i^2}{\|y\|^2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks: in other words, we may reduce the problem to where $x$ is *uniformly* distributed on the sphere's surface.

Comment: Associated Q:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402894/average-value-of-fracxa2xxa3x-over-surface-of-n-dimensional-sphere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For symmetric matrices $A, B$, the quantities $\mathcal R_A(x) = \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$ and $\mathcal R_{A, B}(x) = \frac{x^T Ax}{x^TBx}$ are known as the  [**(generalized) Rayleigh quotient**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient). A question about this was already asked here: [Distribution of the Rayleigh quotient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104958/distribution-of-the-rayleigh-quotient) or here [Expected value of Rayleigh quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906077)

The accepted answer refers to the 1992 book [Quadratic Forms in Random Variables](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243770190_Quadratic_Forms_in_Random_Variables) by Mathai and Provost.

There, on page 144, we are referred to the 1956 paper [Quadratic Forms in Normally Distributed Random Variables](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25048285) by Gurland, where the distribution and the expectation of the generalized Rayleigh Quotient are discussed. Among other things, the author shows:

$$ \mathbf E\left[\frac{x^T Ax}{x^TBx}\right] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{2^{j+2} v^{j+k+1}}c_{j} g_{k} B\left(j+k+1, \frac{3 n}{2}-j-1\right) $$

Here, $B(x, y)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $v$, $c_j$ and $g_k$ are coefficients related to eigenvalues/characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$.

There are many other references giving different series/integral expansions/representations for the moments of $\mathcal R_{A, B}(x)$

- [The Exact Moments of a Ratio of Quadratic Forms in Normal Variables](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20075629) (1986)
- [On the expectation of a ratio of quadratic forms in normal variables](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X89900651) (1989)
- [On the moments of ratios of quadratic forms in normal random variables](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X13000298) (2013)

None of which indicate that there is a general simple "closed form" for $\mathbf E[\mathcal R_{A, B}(x)]$.

---

Some simplification steps we can do in any case, given Eigenvalue Decomposition $B=U^T\Lambda U$:

$$
\mathbf E_{x\sim\mathcal N(0,)}\left[\frac{x^T Ax}{x^TBx}\right] 
= \mathbf E_{y\sim\mathcal N(0,)}\left[\frac{y^TU^T AUy}{y^T \Lambda y}\right]
= \mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}\left[\frac{z^T\Lambda ^{1/2}U^T AU\Lambda ^{1/2}z}{z^T z}\right]
$$

Letting $C=\Lambda ^{1/2}U^T AU\Lambda ^{1/2}$ and using linearity we have:

$$
\mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}\left[\frac{z^TCz}{z^T z}\right]
= \mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}\left[\left\langle C, \;\tfrac{zz^T}{z^T z}\right\rangle\right]
= \left\langle C, \; \mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}\left[\tfrac{zz^T}{z^T z}\right]\right\rangle
$$

Here, both $\mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}[zz^T] = \Lambda$ and $\mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}[z^Tz] = \operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)$ are trivial, however numerical simulation suggests that $\mathbf E_{z\sim\mathcal N(0,\Lambda)}\left[\tfrac{zz^T}{z^T z}\right]$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal has some non-trivial, non-linear relationship w.r.t. $\Lambda$.

Comment: thanks, reading more into this. BTW, in my problem, because of rotational symmetry we can say that `A` is diagonal WLOG

Comment: Using your dot product expansion simplifies things considerably, updated q

Comment: I think that $\Lambda$ should be used instead of $\Lambda^2$ in the expectations of the numerator and denominator of $E[zz^\top/(z^\top z)]$ at the end. Maybe the partial derivatives w.r.t the $\lambda_i$  can help?

Comment: @Yves thanks for spotting that, fixed.

Comment: follow-up question here -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228308/average-value-of-fracxa2xxa3x-over-surface-of-n-dimensional-sphere

Answer (score 2):

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive, so there exists an orthonormal base $U=u_1,...,u_n$ and scalars $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ s.t. $A=UDU^T$, with $D=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 &  & 0 \\
 & \ddots &  \\
0 &  & \lambda_n \\
\end{pmatrix}$. This is the spectral decomposition.

With these, we can decompose $$x^TAx=x^TUDU^Tx$$ and more importantly
$$x^TA^2x=x^TUDU^TUDU^Tx$$. As U is orthonormal, $U^TU=I$ and thus we get the denominator as $x^TA^2x=x^TUD^2U^Tx$.
Now we denote $w=U^Tx$. As a transformation, we get $w\sim N(U^T\mu_x, U^T\Sigma_xU)$. Plug in $x\sim N(0,I_n)$ and we get $w\sim N(0,I_n)$, again using $U^TU=I$.

The numerator is $w^TDw=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_iw_i^Tw_i}$. Denote $g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_i}$, this is simply a $\chi^2_{ng}$ variable ($w^Tw\sim\chi^2_n$, we sum $g$ of those). Similarly, the denominator is a $\chi^2_{nk}$ variable, where $k=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_i^2}$.

Overall, $\frac{x^TAx}{x^TA^2x}=\frac{w^TDw}{w^TD^2w}$ is a ratio of $\chi^2_{ng}$ variable and a $\chi^2_{nk}$ variable, so it has a [beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) with parameters $\left(\alpha=\frac{ng}{2},\beta=\frac{nk}{2}\right)$. Assuming $nk>2$, the mean is

$$ \frac{\alpha}{\beta-1} = \frac{\frac{ng}{2}}{\frac{nk}{2}-1}=\frac{ng}{nk-2} $$

That's the first moment of $\frac{x^TAx}{x^TA^2x}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: I might have missed something with converting it into an $F$ variable? not sure, but the $\beta'$ and $F$ are tightly related.

Comment: Don't you need the two $\chi^2$ variables to be independent to get an $F$ (or a $\beta\prime$)?

Comment: Thanks, will look at this more deeply. BTW because the problem is rotationally symmetric, could just say "A is diagonal WLOG"

Comment: That doesn't seem to match result for A with eigenvalues 1,1/2, the result should be 4/3, verified using 3 different methods -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-ratio-quadratic.nb

Comment: Consider the simple case of $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0.5\\ \end{pmatrix}$ (which satisfies the eigenvalues <1, 0.5>): the quantity will be $\frac{x^TAx}{x^TA^2x}=\frac{x_1^2+0.5x_2^2}{x_1^2+0.25x_2^2}=1+\frac{0.25x_2^2}{x_1^2+0.5x_2^2}$. The last fraction can be written as $\frac{x_2^2}{4x_1^2+x_2^2}$. Let $x_2^2=X\sim\chi^2(1)$ and $4x_1^2=Y\sim\chi^2(4)$, of course $X,Y$ are independent and so the ratio $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ has beta distribution with parameters $(0.5,2)$. Its mean value is $0.5/(2+0.5)=0.2$ and the overall expected value is $1.2$ (rather than 4/3). Try it, even by hand.

Comment: As noted above, this fails because numerator and denominator are dependent in general. Consider for example the special case where $A$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: You could also define $g$ and $k$ as traces, $Tr(A)$ and $Tr(A^2)$ respectively.